# Why does this where clause not return the right record? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
=> #<Gig id: 59, date: "2012-06-01 00:00:00", title: "Awesome Record", url: "http://someurl.com", body: nil, reply_email: nil, industry_id: nil, created_at: "2012-06-03 03:06:45", updated_at: "2012-06-03 03:06:45"> 


1.9.2-p0 :046 > Gig.where(:date => "2012-06-01 00:00:00")
  Gig Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "gigs".* FROM "gigs" WHERE "gigs"."date" = '2012-06-01 00:00:00'
 => [] 
1.9.2-p0 :043 > Gig.where(:date => "2012-06-01")
  Gig Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "gigs".* FROM "gigs" WHERE "gigs"."date" = '2012-06-01'
 => [] 
1.9.2-p0 :044 > Gig.where(:date => "June 01")
  Gig Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "gigs".* FROM "gigs" WHERE "gigs"."date" = 'June 01'
 => [] 
1.9.2-p0 :045 > Gig.where(:date => "June 1")
  Gig Load (32.9ms)  SELECT "gigs".* FROM "gigs" WHERE "gigs"."date" = 'June 1'
 => []
```

All I am trying to do is find the records in this table that have a specific 'date' (or even records that fall within a date range). But the basic where clause above won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1**

I outputted the date as string, via `to_s` and this is the output:

```
d.date
 => Fri, 01 Jun 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00 
1.9.2-p0 :079 > d.date.to_s
 => "2012-06-01 00:00:00 UTC"
```

Not sure if that will help....but I even tried including those strings as the condition of the where clause and it still returns an empty array.

Comment: Not sure but maybe `date` is a reserved keyword. Have you tried the same method with other `datetime` column? such as `created_at`.

Comment: Hrmm....maybe it is a reserved keyword indeed. I didn't try `created_at` or `updated_at` because those fields were generated automagically by Rails, so I know they are good. The `date` field, though, is getting the data from another data source and is being added to the `date` field of each record. So that's why I am testing this one specifically.

Comment: I suggest you to change the name of this field if possible, or maybe try to create an alias for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

```
Gig.where(:date => "2012-06-01 00:00:00 +00.00")
Gig.where("date like '2012-06-01%'")
Gig.where("DATE(date) = '2012-06-01'")
```

Comment: Both `Gig.where("DATE(date) = '2012-06-01'")` & `Gig.where("date like '2012-06-01%'")` work. But the first one does not. You had a typo in the second one by the way, but now it's fixed ;) Why do those work and the first one doesn't?

Comment: Your date is saved as datetime. DATE(date) extracts just the date part of it to compare. The like '...%' is a wild card, ignoring the time part of the date. The UTC part may be getting affected by your time zone settings, or might compare with "2012-06-01 00:00:00 -00.00" or some format like that. Good luck.

Comment: How would I find the records between certain dates? E.g. say between `05-01` and `06-01`?

Comment: Gig.where("DATE(date) >= '2012-05-01' and DATE(date) <= '2012-06-01'")

Comment: This is awesome. To order the above, I would just do:
`Gig.where("DATE(date) >= '2012-05-01' and DATE(date) <= '2012-06-01'").order_by("DATE(date) desc")` This is just to remind myself when I look back on this question in the future, or anyone else that is curious.

Answer (score 0):

Give a shot:

```
Gig.where('date = ?', '2012-06-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Nope....no luck :( I had tried this earlier too....but I just re-tried it to be sure.